# Sample code functionality not working in Android Studio 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am using one option in Android Studio as below:

[image]

Its giving me output like:

> Samples are currently unavailable for: {Symbol: DatePickerFragment,
>   Package: }

Can anyone please tell me when actually it works?

Comment: Why I can not see this option in my Android Studio? Did you enable this from anywhere?

Comment: No, I haven't enabled from anywhere?

Comment: [THIISSS](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/sample-code#inline).

Comment: I want to have this too. :( My Android studio is latest 3.2

Comment: @Jay but its not working

Comment: @PratikButani, it could find the samples because the `samples` directory might be missing from your sdk directory.

Comment: I have `sample` directory and examples in all the API level

Comment: See I have posted question, I want to have this option too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52640107/6891563

Comment: Then it's working properly. I don't think any of the samples have a type as `DatePickerFragment`. Try searching for a method or a variable instead.