# Can not see find-sample-code option in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/sample-code#inline) they tell about **Find Code Sample Option / Import samples**. But I can not see both of them in my Android Studio 3.2.

> 1. In your code, highlight a variable, type, or method.
> 2. Right-click to display the context menu.
> 3. From the context menu, select Find Sample Code.
> 4. The results of your search appear in a tool window as shown in figure 2.

and

> 1. Select File > New > Import Sample.
> 2. Use the search box or the scroll bar to browse the samples.
> 3. When you find a sample that interests you, highlight it and take a look at the preview.
> 4. If you want to import it as a project, click Next and then Finish.

I have tried :

- Selected an variable, right click
- Searched in all actions
- Searched in keymap
- Searched in settings
- Alt + F8 shortcut

Where the option **Find Code Sample** and **Import Sample** exist?

> Perhaps they have removed it?

### Documentation image

[image: their image]

### Should be there

[image: 1]

### No Import Sample option in File>

[image: 1]

### No option in my menu

[image: mine]

### Searched in All Actions, nothing here too

[image: 2]

### Searched in keymap, where are that options?

[image: 4]

Comment: @NileshRathod Is it same bro? He is asking that his option is not working, whether I cant see this option even.

Comment: Test case click first select `RecyclerView.Adapter` than press `alt+F8`

Comment: Tested already bro. Do you have this option in your AS?

Comment: in you above screen shot your are selecting  variable name `adapter.()`  that's might be reason because in my AS option is avaibable

Comment: @NileshRathod they cheated with me. They provided duplicate AS to me. :D, Just checked I don't have `Import Sample` option too.

Comment: @Khemraj, your configuration is haunted. lol

Comment: Why do these all silly things happen with me :(

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio if you are not able to 'Import Sample' option in
`File > New > Import Sample` path, then follow the below steps:

- Open android Studio.
- Go to Settings or Preferences.
- Go to Plugins.
- Search for 'Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio' And check (Turn
  on) this option.

Now, You are able to see 'Import Sample' option.